# Fantasy story series about a boy from a village who has adventures around the world

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading this as a kid and it starts out with:

- a boy in his home village
- where the other kids are mean to him during sports
- and they heat up their home with floating logs or something.

The kid is being hunted by some reaper character and that reaper finds him at a place called "The Edge" or something similar.

He buys a glove covered in an expensive dust that purifies things and is really rare.

In one book they had to climb down the edge for some reason.

There was another part where people only communicated telepathically and when sneaking into somewhere he only thought of light.

One of the main things is the floating ships and how he is really good at flying them and he assembles a team for a mission or something.  There is like float powder and stuff.

I read this close to 10 years ago.

Comment: Please click throughout the Story Id tag to see a list of questions to try to answer to help us help you.

Comment: Your title also needs some work, but I didn't want to edit that.  Syntactically, for one:  the village has adventures?  It should better describe the key aspects of the story:  young boy?  what form of village?  The bit about adventures is okay.

Comment: Alright, after much searching, the series name is The Edge Chronicles. Good stuff, I recommend the read.

Comment: Also confirmed (but not accepted) as the answer here:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23831/fantasy-book-about-a-boy-who-crashes-into-a-world/
This one is probably also it:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137277/looking-for-a-half-remembered-fantasy-novel-with-terrifying-trees/

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by OP in [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157064/fantasy-story-series-about-a-boy-from-a-village-who-has-adventures-around-the-wo#comment418489_157064), this is *The Edge Chronicles* series by Paul Stewart, started in 1998, and still going.

The series is comprised of several character arcs (Twig Saga, Quint Saga, Rock Saga...); the question was mainly looking for the Twig trilogy. See the [How to read *The Edge Chronicles*](https://theedgechronicles.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_read_The_Edge_Chronicles) page on the Wikia for more info on the various suggested orders.

The books narrate the adventures of several main figures in the Edge world, the "Edge" being a cliff that supposedly goes down forever. Flying ships are a main thing in this world, and they underwent several "ages" (stone age, wood age, dust-powered air travel age...).

**A boy in his home village and they heat up their home with floating logs or something.**

Twig, the (human) main character from the original trilogy, was adopted by a community of woodtrolls. He's a bit of an outcast, having been able to walk way earlier than woodtroll kids, being of frail constitution (by comparison), etc.

The woodtrolls use various types of woods for various purposes:

> The woodtrolls had many types of wood to choose from and each had its own special properties. Scentwood, for instance, burned with a fragrance that sent those who breathed it drifting into a dream-filled sleep, while wood from the silvery-turquoise lullabee tree sang as the flames lapped at its bark — strange mournful songs, they were, and not at all to everyone’s taste. And then there was the bloodoak, complete with its parasitic sidekick, a barbed creeper known as tarry vine.
>
> <sub>*Beyond the Deepwoods*, chapter 1, "The Snatchwood Cabin" (first book of Twig, 1998)</sub>

**The other kids are mean to him during sports.**

I'm not sure about it happening during sports, but pursuant to the above description, Twig had a rough childhood, woodtrolls being versed in "law of the jungle" ways:

> This was something he had wished so often as he’d lain in his bunk after yet another day of being teased and taunted and bullied.
>
> <sub>*Beyond the Deepwoods*, chapter 1, "The Snatchwood Cabin" (first book of Twig, 1998)</sub>

...

> Whenever Twig returned to the cabin with a bloodied nose or blacked eyes or clothes covered in slung mud, he wanted his father to wrap him up in his arms and soothe the pain away. Instead, Tuntum would give him advice and make demands.
>
> ‘Bloody their noses,’ he said once. ‘Black their eyes. And throw not mud but dung! Show them what you’re made of.’
>
> Later, when his mother was smoothing hyleberry salve onto his bruises, she would explain that Tuntum was only concerned to prepare him for the harshness of the world outside.
>
> <sub>*Beyond the Deepwoods*, chapter 1, "The Snatchwood Cabin" (first book of Twig, 1998)</sub>

**He buys a glove covered in an expensive dust that purifies things and is really rare.**

That's Phraxdust, a substance originating from Stormphrax crystals.

> "Meanwhile," the caterbird continued, "Vilnix lay in his sick bed, his mind working furiously. He might have failed to harness the power of the lightning, but he realized that the stormphrax dust had created was itself miraculous – a single grain dropped into the foulest water instantly purified it. What would the inhabitants of filthy, fetid Undertown not give for his wonderful dust? "Anything," he whispered greedily. Anything at all!"
>
> <sub>*Stormchaser*, chapter 2, "The Caterbird's Tale" (second book of Twig, 1999)</sub>

And indeed Twig acquires a gauntlet covered in Phraxdust:

> A smile played over the professor's lips. ‘Time!’ he croaked. ‘Time…’ His eyes rolled in his head. ‘Stormphrax breaks down in the twilight of the woods. The twilight, Twig! Not darkness, not light – but twilight. Slowly it crumbles over the centuries, ground down by the pressure of twilight. Ground down, Twig, for hundreds upon hundreds of years, into dust. Phraxdust. The phraxdust that coats the armour of those poor lost knights – that coats the glove you wear.’
>
> <sub>*Stormchaser*, chapter 19, "Screed's looty-booty" (second book of Twig, 1999)</sub>

**In one book they had to climb down the edge for some reason.**

The only book in the Nate Saga (*The Immortals*, 2010) has Nate attempting the "Descent", which is the operation of climbing down the Edge to try and see what lies beyond. Such operations are sometimes attempted, but only one was actually documented, by a descender called Ifflix; Nate, along with Ifflix' brother, pursued the expedition.

**There was another part where people only communicated telepathically.**

These creatures are called waifs, with several sub-species (waterwaifs, nightwaifs etc). They can both read the minds of others and send their own thoughts to people. This is due to them living in the Nightwoods (a forest with no light), where "reading the minds of others is essential for *[their]* survival; a gift to enable *[them]* to see through the darkness" (*The last of the Sky Pirates*, 2002).

They appear in several books in the series.

**And when sneaking into somewhere he only thought of light.**

Once again, that's Nate from *The Immortals* (2010). As his beloved Eudoxia doesn't heal from a bullet wound, he tries to sneak in the Garden of Life to get Riverrise water which could cure her. As he climbs, he focuses his thoughts on a lamplight, as adviced by Healer Barkscale.

> It was all Nate could do to prevent himself thinking about what might lie ahead — but he knew he must not. Second guesses and suppositions were not allowed in his head. Not now. Only the light. The warm, golden light that masked his presence in this strange eerie fastness, halfway up the steep mountainside.
>
> *'Psst!'*
>
> The faint hissing sound broke through the light. Nate acknowledged it, then pushed it aside, filling his head with the light once more as he emerged from his hiding place and looked up. *[...]*
>
> The light, he thought inside his head. Fill your head with the light. Just light. Only light . . .
>
> <sub>*The Immortals* (book of Nate, 2010)</sub>